# Getting IP address in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a web application which allow some specific user to access some resources on the basis of IP address. I am doing IP address check in back end using Java. Now I am going to convert that application to Angular 2. Now how can I do the same thing in Angular 2?

Comment: Eventually your client side IP check is done by JavaScript. The JavaScript on the client machine is not under your control, so your check is useless. Even if your main application is loaded after the ip check, the client can modify whatever he wants in the client side code.

Comment: @Akkusativobjekt so what is the save way to do that.

Comment: Did I send the IP in header to backend for check.

Comment: Search for answers to similar questions or open a new specific one, this is not the place to find a solution.